# Install of pthread on windows error : " Class 'Thread' not found in"

Tags: php, windows, multithreading, xampp, pthreads

I would like to use threads in PHP, so I searched on the web and I found pthread library (https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads).

Like it said in the github, I put pthreadVC2.dll in C:/xamp/php and php_pthreads.dll in C:/xamp/php/ext. But when I run my PHP script the error " Class 'Thread' not found in" pop.

Also, I tried to put "extension=php_pthreads.dll" in my php.ini but same result.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Posix´s threads is provided as an external libary not as a framework code from anywhere. Your php version must be compiled thread safety and posix threads libary must compiled in or installed dynamically.

Comment: Now I have this error : PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pthreads'...